# Simple question about fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

The problem is :

> Let $f : R \rightarrow C$  a continuous function of period one. Supoose that f is Holder continuous with Holder exponent $\alpha > 1$. Then $f$ is constant.

I am trying to use the partials sums of the fourier series in a point $x$ and in a point $y$. But i am getting anywhere.
Someone can give me a hint ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Show that $f$ is differentiable, and its derivative is $0$.

Comment: To be clear, to follow Daniel's suggestion, you don't need to use the periodicity, just the holder condition

Comment: Where do you need Fourier series ? !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right|\le C|h|^{\alpha-1}
$$
Note that there is an extension of Hölder continuity for $k\lt\alpha\lt k+1$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$:
$$
f\in C^k\quad\text{and}\quad\left|\Delta_h^kf(x)\right|\le C|h|^\alpha
$$
which is equivalent to $f^{(k)}$ having Hölder exponent $\alpha-k$.